# Drupal 7 - Webform module - Filter the results

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-webform

I am using **Webform** module with **Drupal 7** and want to have the *Results* tab showing the submissions based on the user and their country they belong to, which is set in their profile during registration (can only be a unique value).

The idea is that logged in user should see all submitted results from users who have their Country name in common. So, if I belong to *Country-A*, I should be able to see entries of all users who belong to *Country-A* (currently, it is showing results for all countries inclusive).

I realized that the result of **Webform** module is based on Drupal-Views. I have spent hours to do this but with no luck. Can anyone please suggest how to configure this with Drupal-Views (contextual filters)?

-- I need to use the following value for country --

```
<pre>global $user;
$user_fields = user_load($user->uid);
$user_fields->field_country['und']['0']['value']; // Has the country name</pre>
```

Comment: Why not Views? It could show "Webform submissions" and you could configure Contextual filters to filter by current user country and throw 403 if country is different

Comment: My client wants this feature to be applied to Webform only. I added more detail, perhaps you can suggest me something again now.

Comment: @Paradoxetion: I realized that _Webform_ is using Views to show its results. Can you please guide me how to filter the values? I somehow managed to show up the country names in the submitted (Views) data. But I am not able configure appropriate conditions inside Views to eliminate un-required fields (for I also don't know where and how they are stored in tables). I think you have solution for my problem. :)